# php echo hidden form fields

Tags: php, loops, foreach, hidden-field

I am trying to extract the value form some hidden text fields and not quite sure how to do it.

The fields are stored in an array and then outputted in a loop.

I have several fields like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[0]" value="1336"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[1]" value="1337"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[2]" value="1338"/>
```

How would i go about extracting the values from the above? I have tried the following but with no joy:

```
$posts =  $_REQUEST['variable_post_id'];
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   echo $post;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$posts =  $_POST['variable_post_id'];
```

And make sure that you kept these hiddenfields within the form and your html would be like

```
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1336"/>
```

Comment: I have already tried this. Just tried it again and i get the following: Undefined index: variable_post_id[]

Answer (score 0):

well your codes look fine.. but you dont have to add index in your input html, make sure these fields is inside the `<form>` tag and you can use `$_POST` or `$_GET` instead of requested according to your form's method

try this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1336"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1337"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1338"/>


$posts =  $_REQUEST['variable_post_id'];
foreach ($posts as $post) {
 echo $post;

}
```

Comment: i dont add the index, it's automatically added via wordpress

Comment: @danyo from where they(hidden fields) are rendering..??

Answer (score 0):

Try it without numbers

```
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1336"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1337"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1338"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is ok, you should use `form` and no need to add `index` in your `form field` like,

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1336"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1337"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[]" value="1338"/>
    <input type="submit" calue="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $posts =  $_REQUEST['variable_post_id'];
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
           echo $post;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the id inside the brackets, you can do something like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[id][0]" value="1336"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[id][1]" value="1337"/>
<input type="hidden" name="variable_post_id[id][2]" value="1338"/>

$posts =  $_REQUEST['variable_post_id'];
foreach ($posts["id"] as $post) {
   echo $post;

}
```

Or if you wanted to access a specific one:

```
echo $posts["id"][0];
```